# Transparent Database Encryption for SQL server 2017 on linux with standard edition

Tags: sql-server-2017

We need to Encrypt data at rest.

Currently we are using SQL Server 2017 on Ubuntu, with Standard Edition. We are using AWS for managing servers.

I tried to do TDE but it always show me below error.

Transparent Data Encryption is not available in the edition of this SQL Server instance. See books online for more details on feature support in different SQL Server editions.

Is there any way to encrypt the database with standard edition only. If yes then what are the steps & If no then which third party tool is best.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Microsoft on-line documentation, TDE is explicitly available only in Enterprise edition.

The matrix in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017 is unambiguous :

Feature / Enterprise /Standard / Web / Express / Express with Advanced Services

Transparent database encryption / Yes / No / No / No / No

I don't know of any option to have the sqlserver database encrypted at rest.

Now, if you're ready/able to modify your setup, you can have a look at the "Always Encrypted" feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), available in all editions.

With this feature, you can choose to encrypt some of your columns, and have the driver (eg: jdbc driver) automatically decrypt them for you (so you don't have to modify your SQL queries, only the connection). There are some serious limitations on what you can do, but it may be worth to have a look.